# Browse a SQL-Dump file without importing it into a DBMS?

Tags: sql, mysql, viewer

Is somebody aware of a tool that lets me browse MySQL-Files without having to import them into my database system?
I'm looking for an easy way to inspect MySQL Backups quickly without having to import them - but still being nicely displayed, so viewing the SQL source is not really an option.

Maybe there's a program that takes the SQL dump and automatically imports it into a temporary database, then presenting it in an interface similar to HeidiSQL (or any other SQL-Gui-Tool).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you eliminating the obvious solution?  You just need to load the backup into a mysql database.  Either load the backup into a separate mysql instance, or if your backup is of just one database (i.e. you didn't pass `--databases` or `--all-databases` to `mysqldump`), load it into a database of a different name.

Comment: Especially if you don't load all the data into the database, this would be as good as any other solution. You'll need to scan the full dump anyhow.

Comment: Yes the most common thing to do is importing/loading it into a temporary newly created schema. But sometimes, we only need to see some tiny part of it's contents; which I usually achieve by opening it with notepad. A tiny utility which present the table contents in more tidy format will be nice. This utility may ignore everything else.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for an answer to the same question, because it can be cumbersome to wait to load a 20 GB sql dump just for inspection and drop again.  While I hope to find a standalone shortcut tool, best I can recommend is a cocktail of linux cli text manipulation tools like grep, sed, and cut. Some useful output could be:

- What tables are being created/inserted into?
- Are the mysqldump INSERTs one line-per-record or all stuffed into one? (Because this can affect other things like)
- How many rows are being inserted into table XYZ?
- What is some representative data being inserted into table XYZ?
- What is the ABC column value for the last row inserted into table XYZ?

Good luck!

Comment: One more thought: Just stumbled across this interesting tool https://github.com/thirtysixthspan/hasten which appears to at least speed up the load by disabling indexing at the right time ¯\_(ツ)_/¯